# CSS file added dynamically is not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a JavaScript widget that uses angular and NVD3 libraries to display certain graphs. In the script file (located in the server) that contains the code for generating these graphs I have added the code for adding dynamically the script files pointing to these libraries, in addition to the CSS file (nv.d3.css) used by NVD3 to render properly its elements:

```
loadScript('http://localhost:3000/javascript/bower_components/angular/angular.js');
loadScript('http://localhost:3000/javascript/bower_components/d3/d3.js');
loadScript('http://localhost:3000/javascript/bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js');
loadScript('http://localhost:3000/javascript/bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.js');

var css = document.createElement('style');
css.type = 'text/css';
css.setAttribute('src', 'http://localhost:3000/javascript/bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.css');
$("body").append(css);

function loadScript(address){
    var angularnvd3Script = document.createElement('script');
    angularnvd3Script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    angularnvd3Script.setAttribute('src', address);
    $("body").append(angularnvd3Script);
}
```

When the client application embedding the widget runs, the scripts are loaded successfully, the graphs are shown correctly from a data point of view, the CSS file seems to be added correctly too in the client HTML file, yet it is not used, as the style of the graphs is not picked up. I have tried to add the file in the head instead of the body, but the same unexpected behaviour occurs.

Where might the problem be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you're mixing two ways to add CSS to your page. You can either use the `style` tag or the `link` tag.

By using the `style` tag you can't use `href` so in your case you have to use the `link` approach:

```
var link = document.createElement('link')
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet')
link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css')
link.setAttribute('href', 'http://localhost:3000/javascript/bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.css')
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link)
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to point out, the combination of a `link` and a `style` tag doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no onload support for stylesheets in most modern browsers.  There is a solution I found with a little Googling.

**Cited from:** http://thudjs.tumblr.com/post/637855087/stylesheet-onload-or-lack-thereof

#### The basics

The most basic implementation of this can be done in a measely 30 lines of — framework independent — JavaScript code:

```
function loadStyleSheet( path, fn, scope ) {
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0], // reference to document.head for appending/ removing link nodes
       link = document.createElement( 'link' );           // create the link node
   link.setAttribute( 'href', path );
   link.setAttribute( 'rel', 'stylesheet' );
   link.setAttribute( 'type', 'text/css' );

   var sheet, cssRules;
// get the correct properties to check for depending on the browser
   if ( 'sheet' in link ) {
      sheet = 'sheet'; cssRules = 'cssRules';
   }
   else {
      sheet = 'styleSheet'; cssRules = 'rules';
   }

   var interval_id = setInterval( function() {                     // start checking whether the style sheet has successfully loaded
          try {
             if ( link[sheet] && link[sheet][cssRules].length ) { // SUCCESS! our style sheet has loaded
                clearInterval( interval_id );                      // clear the counters
                clearTimeout( timeout_id );
                fn.call( scope || window, true, link );           // fire the callback with success == true
             }
          } catch( e ) {} finally {}
       }, 10 ),                                                   // how often to check if the stylesheet is loaded
       timeout_id = setTimeout( function() {       // start counting down till fail
          clearInterval( interval_id );             // clear the counters
          clearTimeout( timeout_id );
          head.removeChild( link );                // since the style sheet didn't load, remove the link node from the DOM
          fn.call( scope || window, false, link ); // fire the callback with success == false
       }, 15000 );                                 // how long to wait before failing

   head.appendChild( link );  // insert the link node into the DOM and start loading the style sheet

   return link; // return the link node;
}
```

This would allow you to load a style sheet with an onload callback function like this:

```
loadStyleSheet( '/path/to/my/stylesheet.css', function( success, link ) {
   if ( success ) {
      // code to execute if the style sheet was loaded successfully
   }
   else {
      // code to execute if the style sheet failed to successfully
   }
} );
```

Or if you want to your callback to maintain its scope/ context, you could do something kind of like this:

```
loadStyleSheet( '/path/to/my/stylesheet.css', this.onComplete, this );
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should append css node in head but to body!

You can try:

```
$('head').append(css)
```